# What is the "right" hermitian structure on tensor products of quantum group representations?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, quantum-groups, unitary-representations, tensor-products, rt.representation-theory

This is pretty specific, but there are some experts around.

So, in Chari & Pressley, it's explained that in the standard *-structure, every irreducible, finite-dimensional representation of a quantum group (at a generic parameter) is unitary.  Is it written somewhere what the "right" unitary structure on a tensor product of these representations is?

I ask because if one categorifies such representations, one gets a unitary structure essentially for free, so it would extremely useful if someone had already written down one I could match up with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know these are all about the root of unity case, but you might look at [this paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1358983) by Kirillov, and [this one](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1470857) by Wenzl.

Comment: The paper by Wenzl wins it. Admittedly, it's focused on the root of unity case, but contains exactly the generic stuff I needed.

Comment: *-structures come in kinds, ones where q*=q (so q is behaving like a real number) and ones where q*=q^-1 (so q is behaving like a complex number of size one).  So if the *-structure that you're coming up with is the latter kind that's saying that morally q is behaving like a root of unity (or at least like something of norm one) even though as a degree shift it makes no sense to set q to a complex number.